# what is the difference between subview and subclass

Tags: ios, iphone

Well, the title says it all. What is the difference (if any) between subview and subclass? Is a subview also a subclass? e.g. when the app launches, the main View is a subview of UIWindow, but UIWindow is a subclass of UIView.

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad.  As a quick pointer: the concepts are independent.  Read about subclasses here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming and about windows and subviews here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

The UIWindow is a subview of UIView *becuase* the UIWindow is a subclass of UIView. The same concept holds true in other object oriented languages. I can have a super class called **Vehicle** with subclasses *car* and *motorcycle*. The car and the motorcycle are 'subVehicles' of Vehicle...just like UIWindow is a subclass and therefore 'subView' of UIView.

Comment: This is incorrect. The window is not a subview of the main view, it's the other way around. Whether something is a subview of another view has nothing to do with whether it's also a subclass of that view.